# Jetpack compose Canvas detect segment touch

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack compose to draw a circle which contains multiple segments

[image]

```
  BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { position: Offset ->
                    val isSegmentTouched = this.isSegmentTouched(
                        pointerInputScope = this,
                        position = position,
                        circleDiameter = maxWidth,
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidth
                    )
                    if (isSegmentTouched) {
                        var currentAngle = startAngle

                        val touchAngle = this.calculateTouchAngle(
                            chartStartAngle = startAngle,
                            xPos = position.x,
                            yPos = position.y
                        )
  }
```

This is how the segments and the images are drawn

```
 val width = size.width
            val radius = width / 2f

            if (spendingChartItems.isNotEmpty() && totalAmount > 0) {
                val circumference = 2 * Math.PI * (radius - strokeWidth.toPx() / 2)
                val strokeAngle =
                    delimiterCoefficient * (strokeWidth.toPx() / circumference * 180f).toFloat()

                var currentAngle = startAngle

                spendingChartItems.forEach { spendingChartItem ->
                    drawCircleArch(
                        spendingRingItem = spendingChartItem,
                        circleDiameter = radius * 2,
                        strokeAngle = if (spendingChartItems.size == 1) 0f else strokeAngle,
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
                        drawScope = this,
                        startAngle = currentAngle,
                    )

                    val iconSize = getIconSize(
                        percent = spendingChartItem.adjustedPercentage,
                        minSize = minIconSize,
                        maxSize = maxIconSizeDp
                    )
                    drawCategoryImage(
                        drawScope = this,
                        circleRadius = radius,
                        segmentWidth = strokeWidth,
                        startAngle = currentAngle,
                        spendingRingItem = spendingChartItem,
                        iconWith = iconSize.dp,
                        context = context
                    )
                    currentAngle += spendingChartItem.archAngle
                }
```

And this is how each segment is drawn

```
private fun drawCircleArch(
    spendingRingItem: SpendingRingItem,
    circleDiameter: Float,
    startAngle: Float,
    strokeAngle: Float,
    strokeWidth: Dp,
    drawScope: DrawScope,
    strokeCap: StrokeCap = StrokeCap.Round
) {
    drawScope.apply {
        drawArc(
            color = spendingRingItem.colour,
            startAngle = startAngle + strokeAngle,
            sweepAngle = spendingRingItem.archAngle - strokeAngle * 2,
            useCenter = false,
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = strokeWidth.toPx() / 2,
                y= strokeWidth.toPx() / 2),
            size = Size(
                width = circleDiameter - strokeWidth.toPx(),
                height = circleDiameter - strokeWidth.toPx()
            ),
            style = Stroke(
                strokeWidth.toPx(),
                cap = strokeCap
            )
        )
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is being able to click on a segment and redirect the user to a specific screen.
I was able to determine if the user taps on any of the segment in the ring using

```
pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { position: Offset ->
                    val isSegmentTouched = this.isSegmentTouched(
                        pointerInputScope = this,
                        position = position,
                        circleDiameter = maxWidth,
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidth
                    )
                    if (isSegmentTouched) {
                        var currentAngle = startAngle

                        val touchAngle = this.calculateTouchAngle(
                            chartStartAngle = startAngle,
                            xPos = position.x,
                            yPos = position.y
                        )
```

```
internal fun PointerInputScope.isSegmentTouched(
    pointerInputScope: PointerInputScope,
    position: Offset,
    circleDiameter: Dp,
    strokeWidth: Dp
): Boolean {
    val xPos = pointerInputScope.size.center.x - position.x
    val yPos = pointerInputScope.size.center.y - position.y
    val distanceFromCenter = sqrt(xPos * xPos + yPos * yPos)
    //entire radius of the circle
    val outerRadius = circleDiameter.toPx() / 2
    //the radius of the circle minus the segment width
    val innerRadius = outerRadius - strokeWidth.toPx()
    val segmentDistancesFromCenter = innerRadius..outerRadius
    return distanceFromCenter in segmentDistancesFromCenter
}
```

on the canvas. But I need to determine which one of the individual segment is clicked. Not only that but also detect if the user clicks on an icon next to the segment

This is how the circle looks like. I want to determine on that highlighted area which item corresponds to that specific segment

Comment: @Thracian could you give me a hand on this ?

Comment: He has a sample for this already in his repo

Comment: https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter6_graphics/chart/PieChart.kt have you look at this!